# MapView's Overlay's onTap to call a method in the activity

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, android-maps

I would like to have a Spinner updated upon an onTap event in my overlay items.
What is the best practice in this situation? Should I pass the Spinner to the overlay items? The method to update the Spinner is currently in the MapActivity, is there a way to invoke it from the onTap event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar thing, and I ended up passing the Spinner to my `Overlay` in the constructor.  Then you can update the array adapter of the `Spinner` inside your `Overlay` code.  Hope it works!